# FlashDevelop and theme compilation

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flashdevelop

How to compile a theme using FD 3 or 4?

I have a CSS file with assets and would like to get a SWC file (not SWF) like halo.swc

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is not supported natively in Flash Develop. However there is apparently [one person who has written a plugin for doing that](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2987&sid=28ee70eb7f7ff1f86c0c0f46b0a8d30b).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ancide. Installed that plugin but I have problem with compiling it: "C:\Program Files\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\bin\compc.exe" -load-config+="D:\work\eve-theme\obj\eve-theme.flex.compc.xml" 
Error: nothing was specified to be included in the library

I have a project with just assets dir and style.css.

Answer (score -1):

select your CSS file then Right click CSS -> Choose convert to SWF option. It automatically convert to css to swf. No need to compile them .

It's my opinion. may be you will get better answer from others .

Comment: Also, FlashDevelop doesn't have Convert to SWF option, it is implemented in Flash Builder